# NSXMLParser not working

Tags: ios, http, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse some XML data from a URL. Its almost working, but the expected data isn't being logged.

Here is a sample of the xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <result>
<row>
 <id>1</id>
 <menu_id>1</menu_id>
 <group_id>1</group_id>
 <name>Merchandise</name>
 <image>bag of beans.jpg</image>
</row> 
<row>
 <id>4</id>
 <menu_id>1</menu_id>
 <group_id>1</group_id>
 <name>Misc</name>
 <image>tea.jpg</image>
</row>
```

And here is my code:

```
#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    // If you have a more complex object you could init here
    // Since I'm just storing a string I won't do anything
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
   // NSLog(@"didStartElement - %@", elementName);
    }
    }
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (!self->currentStringValue) {
    self->currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   // NSLog(@"didStartElement - %@", string);

    }


    [self->currentStringValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        NSString *currentStringValue = [self->currentStringValue
                                stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    self->currentStringValue = nil;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
            self->ourExpectedElementValue = currentStringValue;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentStringValue);
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the XML data, there is more than one 'name' element and the 3rd to last line that reads

```
NSLog(@"%@",currentStringValue);
```

is meant to log all values within all the `<name>` tags, but instead it logs only this:

```
2013-07-31 19:02:56.394 Touch2Go[1775:11303] Merchandise
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code logs both "Merchandise" and "Misc". To avoid a parser error, I added the missing `</result>` to the XML data.

Comment: but there isn't a <result> tag. Is that the problem?

Comment: You have a starting `<result>` tag in the first line. And yes, without that it would not work.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just copyed + pasted the very first part of it for the sake of ease, theres much more, and the code does end with </result>, so I dont think the problem is there.

Comment: But then I cannot reproduce the problem with your code and your data.

Comment: Can you please show me your whole code then??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34554/discussion-between-martin-r-and-coder101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, the XML data did not have a *single top-level element*
as required by the XML specification, so it looked like this:

```
<row> 
    ...
</row>
<row> 
    ...
</row>
<row> 
    ...
</row>
```

The parser stops parsing after the first complete "row" tag (and returns with an error condition). If the  data is enclosed in a single top-level element

```
<result> 
   <row> 
       ...
   </row>
   <row> 
       ...
   </row>
   <row> 
       ...
   </row>
</result>
```

then all elements are parsed as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take array. when it is fetch the string from xml you have to add this in array in didEndElement method.